# What is that? A black cloud?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-tekkit

I started playing tekkit today and suddenly saw this:

[image]

what is this?

Comment: The remains of an enderman when it teleports if im not mistaken, that or the rift energy. cant tell which from here

Comment: How long was it there?

Answer (score 5):

That's an [inactive rift](http://wiki.technicpack.net/Rifts) from a (pocket dimension) dungeon from the [Dimensional Doors](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/1650007-151universal-dimensional-doors-v134-physics-what-physics/) mod by StevenRS11. If you place a [Wooden Warp Door](http://wiki.technicpack.net/Wooden_Warp_Door) on the block just below it you'll make it permanent and be able to enter it. One-way exits of such pocket dimensions also look like this, but you would know if you created one.

Make sure you have some way to come back in case you'll destroy the exit door on the other side - like a [Mystcraft](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/918541-151-mystcraft-0103/) [Linking Book](http://wiki.technicpack.net/Linking_Book) - else you'll have to cheat your way back using `/tpx 0` or similar commands.

You can use a [Rift Remover](http://wiki.technicpack.net/Rift_Remover) to get rid of it. Equip the remover and right-click on the black cloud for it to disappear forever.

Comment: you just saved my house, the black cloud was consuming my room after I broke a pocket dimension door

Comment: Links to items are dead.